# List of Japanese counter words

Tags: numbers, suffixes, counters

What are the essential Japanese counter words?

For example -dai for machines, -mai for papers and stuff like that.

- What else to expect/know?

Thank you

Comment: Define essential? If you want absolutely essential then the basic 一つ、 二つ series will do fine. Do you mean a certain school grade or JLPT level? Or do you mean what a Japanese native adult would be expected to know?

Comment: We try to avoid questions that are considered "general reference" questions that can easily be answered with a link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information. The answers posted here contain such references. If you have a reference or translation question about something not easily looked up, feel free to ask *those* questions. I am going to leave you with those references and close this. Thanks.

Comment: Well but this question WILL come, so it's better that it's already here.

Answer (score 9):

The [article at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word) covers the common ones as well as a decent number of extended ones, and lists the exceptions for days, people, etc. as well as rendaku and number word changes (e.g. 300->san*bya*ku, 4:00-> *yo*ji).

Answer (score 6):

There are entire dictionaries for this (数え方の辞典). [Here's](http://www.hyou.net/ka/kazoekata.htm) a link to a whole bunch.
個 (ko) is the most commonly used one. Japanese people use it often even with words that should have a special counter if it's a less-often used one. It can sometimes be annoying even for them to think of the proper 数詞! Here are most common ones I can think of:

- 人 (nin) for people
- 名（様）[mei sama] for people, used when referring to number of customers at restaurants, etc.
- 本 (hon) for long skinny stuff (pencils, pillars)
- 冊 (satu) for bound stuff (books, magazines)
- 枚 (mai) for flat stuff (paper, cds、shirts)
- 台 (dai) for machines like cars and computers
- 匹 (hiki) for most animals (four legged, insects, fish, etc.)

  - For some other animals:
  - 頭 (tou) for cattle
  - 羽 (wa) for birds and sometimes rabbits
- 回、度(kai, do) for number of times an action occurs
- 隻 (sen) for big ships

Etc. The list goes on. I happened to live near a harbor so the last one was useful for me (though it was still often substituted with 個!). You can just learn the few most common ones and use 個 for everything else, learning the less common ones as you go.

Comment: don't forget 羽 is for rabbits too!

Comment: 羽 and 匹 can both be used

Comment: 匹 is used alot by Japanese people, but it is not correct.  羽 is grammatically correct.

Comment: "+ 船 (sen) for ships". Really? Don't see this in the page you link to. Sure you don't mean 隻 or 艘?

Comment: @MarkHosang who decides what is correct or not if not the people using the language?

Comment: The Yokohama City's song says:
今は[百]{もも}[船]{ふね}[百]{もも}[千]{ち}[船]{ふね}[泊]{と}まるところぞ見よや
Nowadays, we can see hundreds or thousands of ships staying in the (Yokohama) harbor.

Comment: @MarkHosang Would you send me a source for 匹 being grammatically incorrect? I would definitely think it were ungrammatical if someone said さかな二羽.

Comment: @NateGlenn Traditionally speaking 羽 was the counter for rabbits.  However, recently 匹 has also become commonplace and the validity of 匹 for use with rabbits is up for debate even among Japanese.

Comment: @MarkHosang- Ah, for rabbits, yes I am familiar with that. Your original comment makes it sound like 羽 is correct for, say, dogs and fish. I'll update my answer a little.